# Best queue driver to send push notifications in social networking application

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, message-queue

I am working on social networking application. On application 50k+ users are registered and they are performing different tasks like posting ,comment, post likes and follow to each other I have to send to push notification to devices if any action perform by any user. If I see this scenario then I have sent atleast 50K+ push notification per day. So now I want to send these notifications through queue. I am confuse to take decision to select the queue driver for queueing that scalable and can work fastly with heady data of queueing without downtime and high scalable. i hosted my code on amazon aws server.

Kindly guide in a write direction and help to take best decision for queue driver.

Thanks in advance